# Catch-22 situation with Common Lisp macros

Tags: macros, common-lisp, eval

Often when I try to write a macro, I run up against the following difficulty: I need one form that is passed to the macro to be evaluated before being processed by a helper function that is invoked while generating the macro's expansion. In the following example, we are only interested in how we could write a macro to emit the code we want, and not in the uselessness of the macro itself:

Imagine (bear with me) a version of Common Lisp's `lambda` macro, where only the number of arguments is important, and the names and order of the arguments are not. Let's call it `jlambda`. It would be used like so:

```
(jlambda 2
  ...body)
```

where `2` is the arity of the function returned. In other words, this produces a binary operator.

Now imagine that, given the arity, `jlambda` produces a dummy lambda-list which it passes to the actual `lambda` macro, something like this:

```
(defun build-lambda-list (arity)
  (assert (alexandria:non-negative-integer-p arity))
  (loop for x below arity collect (gensym)))

(build-lambda-list 2)
==> (#:G15 #:G16)
```

The expansion of the above call to `jlambda` will look like this:

```
(lambda (#:G15 #:16)
  (declare (ignore #:G15 #:16))
  …body))
```

Let's say we need the `jlambda` macro to be able to receive the arity value as a Lisp form that evaluates to a non-negative integer (as opposed to receiving a non-negative integer directly) eg:

```
(jlambda (+ 1 1)
  ...body)
```

The form `(+ 1 1)` needs to be evaluated, then the result needs to be passed to `build-lambda-list` and that needs to be evaluated, and the result of that is inserted into the macro expansion.

```
(+ 1 1)
=> 2
(build-lambda-list 2)
=> (#:G17 #:18)

(jlambda (+ 1 1) ...body)
=> (lambda (#:G19 #:20)
     (declare (ignore #:G19 #:20))
       …body))
```

So here's a version of `jlambda` that works when the arity is provided as a number directly, but not when it's passed as a form to be evaluated:

```
(defun jlambda-helper (arity)
  (let ((dummy-args (build-lambda-list arity)))
  `(lambda ,dummy-args
     (declare (ignore ,@dummy-args))
       body)))

(defmacro jlambda (arity &body body)
  (subst (car body) 'body (jlambda-helper arity)))

(jlambda 2 (print “hello”))  ==> #<anonymous-function>

(funcall *
         'ignored-but-required-argument-a
         'ignored-but-required-argument-b)
==> “hello”
    “hello”

(jlambda (+ 1 1) (print “hello”)) ==> failed assertion in build-lambda-list, since it receives (+ 1 1) not 2
```

I could evaluate the `(+ 1 1)` using the sharp-dot read macro, like so:

```
(jlambda #.(+ 1 1) (print “hello”)) ==> #<anonymous-function>
```

But then the form cannot contain references to lexical variables, since they are not available when evaluating at read-time:

```
(let ((x 1))
  ;; Do other stuff with x, then:
  (jlambda #.(+ x 1) (print “hello”))) ==> failure – variable x not bound
```

I could quote all body code that I pass to `jlambda`, define it as a function instead, and then `eval` the code that it returns:

```
(defun jlambda (arity &rest body)
  (let ((dummy-args (build-lambda-list arity)))
  `(lambda ,dummy-args
     (declare (ignore ,@dummy-args))
       ,@body)))

(eval (jlambda (+ 1 1) `(print “hello”))) ==> #<anonymous-function>
```

But I can't use `eval` because, like sharp-dot, it throws out the lexical environment, which is no good.

So `jlambda` must be a macro, because I don't want the function body code evaluated until the proper context for it has been established by `jlambda`'s expansion; however it must also be a function, because I want the first form (in this example, the arity form) evaluated before passing it to helper functions that generate the macro expansion. How do I overcome this Catch-22 situation?

**EDIT**

In response to @Sylwester 's question, here's an explanation of the context:

I'm writing something akin to an [“esoteric programming language”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language), implemented as a DSL in Common Lisp. The idea (admittedly silly but potentially fun) is to force the programmer, as far as possible (I'm not sure how far yet!), to write exclusively in [point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming). To do this, I will do several things:

- Use [curry-compose-reader-macros](http://eschulte.github.io/curry-compose-reader-macros/) to provide most of the functionality required to write in point-free style in CL
- Enforce functions' arity – i.e. override CL's default behaviour that allows functions to be variadic
- Instead of using a type system to determine when a function has been “fully applied” (like in Haskell), just manually specify a function's arity when defining it.

So I'll need a custom version of `lambda` for defining a function in this silly language, and – if I can't figure that out - a custom version of `funcall` and/or `apply` for invoking those functions. Ideally they'll just be skins over the normal CL versions that change the functionality slightly.

A function in this language will somehow have to keep track of its arity. However, for simplicity, I would like the procedure itself to still be a funcallable CL object, but would really like to avoid using the MetaObject Protocol, since it's even more confusing to me than macros.

A potentially simple solution would be to use a closure. Every function could simply close over the binding of a variable that stores its arity. When invoked, the arity value would determine the exact nature of the function application (i.e. full or partial application). If necessary, the closure could be “pandoric” in order to provide external access to the arity value; that could be achieved using `plambda` and `with-pandoric` from [Let Over Lambda](http://letoverlambda.com/).

In general, functions in my language will behave like so (potentially buggy pseudocode, purely illustrative):

```
Let n be the number of arguments provided upon invocation of the function f of arity a.
If a = 0 and n != a, throw a “too many arguments” error;
Else if a != 0 and 0 < n < a, partially apply f to create a function g, whose arity is equal to a – n;
Else if n > a, throw a “too many arguments” error;
Else if n = a, fully apply the function to the arguments (or lack thereof).
```

The fact that the arity of `g` is equal to `a – n` is where the problem with `jlambda` would arise: `g` would need to be created like so:

```
(jlambda (- a n)
  ...body)
```

Which means that access to the lexical environment is a necessity.

Comment: Wikipedia on [Catch-22 situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)): _A catch-22 is a paradoxical situation from which an individual cannot escape because of contradictory rules. An example would be:
To get a job, you need to have a few years of experience. But in order to gain experience, you need to get a job first._ (never heard that term before)

Comment: There is one thing that bugs me a little: how do you use those arguments? what would be an example of a body for those jlambda? This is a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: @coredump Based on the sample code including things like `(declare (ignore ,@dummy-args))`, I think the point is that the function has a particular arity, but *doesn't* use it's arguments.  Kind of like CL's [**constantly**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm) which takes any number of arguments, but always returns the same value, these functions would take a certain fixed number of arguments, but always evaluate the same body.

Answer (score 6):

This is a particularly tricky situation because there's no obvious way to create a function of a particular number of arguments *at runtime*.  If there's no way to do that, then it's probably easiest to write a a function that takes an arity and another function, and wraps the function in a new function that requires that is provided the particular number of arguments:

```
(defun %jlambda (n function)
  "Returns a function that accepts only N argument that calls the
provided FUNCTION with 0 arguments."
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (unless (eql n (length args))
      (error "Wrong number of arguments."))
    (funcall function)))
```

Once you have that, it's easy to write the macro around it that you'd like to be able to:

```
(defmacro jlambda (n &body body)
  "Produces a function that takes exactly N arguments and and evalutes
the BODY."
  `(%jlambda ,n (lambda () ,@body)))
```

And it behaves roughly the way you'd want it to, including letting the arity be something that isn't known at compile time.

```
CL-USER> (let ((a 10) (n 7))
           (funcall (jlambda (- a n)
                      (print 'hello))
                    1 2 3))

HELLO 
HELLO
CL-USER> (let ((a 10) (n 7))
           (funcall (jlambda (- a n)
                      (print 'hello))
                    1 2))
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Wrong number of arguments." {1004B95E63}>.
```

Now, you *might* be able to do something that invokes the compiler at runtime, possibly indirectly, using **coerce**, but that won't let the body of the function be able to refer to variables in the original lexical scope, though you *would* get the implementation's wrong number of arguments exception:

```
(defun %jlambda (n function)
  (let ((arglist (loop for i below n collect (make-symbol (format nil "$~a" i)))))
    (coerce `(lambda ,arglist
               (declare (ignore ,@arglist))
               (funcall ,function))
            'function)))

(defmacro jlambda (n &body body)
  `(%jlambda ,n (lambda () ,@body)))
```

This works in SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (let ((a 10) (n 7))
           (funcall (jlambda (- a n)
                      (print 'hello))
                    1 2 3))
HELLO 

CL-USER> (let ((a 10) (n 7))
           (funcall (jlambda (- a n)
                      (print 'hello))
                    1 2))
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR "invalid number of arguments: ~S" {1005259923}>.
```

While this works in SBCL, it's not clear to me whether it's actually guaranteed to work.  We're using **coerce** to compile a function that has a literal function object in it.  I'm not sure whether that's portable or not.

Comment: Brilliant! This is certainly a simple and elegant solution. Thanks also for mentioning that you can `coerce` to a function, I didn't know that.

Comment: I second the "Brilliant" comment. I was trying to do something similar a while back and gave up. Thanks Joshua Taylor for the insight!

Answer (score 4):

**NB:** *In your code you use strange quotes so that `(print “hello”)` doesn't actually print `hello` but the whatever the variable `“hello”` evaluates to, while `(print "hello")` does what one would expect.*

My first question is why? Usually you know how many arguments you are taking compile time or at least you just make it multiple arity. Making an `n` arity function only gives you errors when passwd with wrong number of arguments as added feature with the drawback of using `eval` and friends.

It cannot be solved as a macro since you are mixing runtime with macro expansion time. Imagine this use:

```
(defun test (last-index)
  (let ((x (1+ last-index)))
    (jlambda x (print "hello"))))
```

The macro is expanded when this form is evaluated and the content replaced before the function is assigned to `test`. At this time `x` doesn't have any value whatsoever and sure enough the macro function only gets the symbols so that the result need to use this value. `lambda` is a special form so it again gets expanded right after the expansion of `jlambda`, also before any usage of the function.

There is nothing lexical happening since this happens before the program is running. It could happen before loading the file with `compile-file` and then if you load it will load all forms with the macros already expanded beforehand.

With [`compile`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/f_cmp.htm#compile) you can make a function from data. It is probably as evil as `eval` is so you shouldn't be using it for common tasks, but they exist for a reason:

```
;; Macro just to prevent evaluation of the body 
(defmacro jlambda (nexpr &rest body)
  `(let ((dummy-args (build-lambda-list ,nexpr)))
     (compile nil (list* 'lambda dummy-args ',body))))
```

So the expansion of the first example turns into this:

```
(defun test (last-index)
  (let ((x (1+ last-index)))
    (let ((dummy-args (build-lambda-list x))) 
      (compile nil (list* 'lambda dummy-args '((print "hello")))))))
```

This looks like it could work. Lets test it:

```
(defparameter *test* (test 10))
(disassemble *test*)
;Disassembly of function nil
;(CONST 0) = "hello"
;11 required arguments <!-- this looks right
;0 optional arguments
;No rest parameter
;No keyword parameters
;4 byte-code instructions:
;0     (const&push 0)                      ; "hello"
;1     (push-unbound 1)
;3     (calls1 142)                        ; print
;5     (skip&ret 12)
;nil
```

## Possible variations

I've made a macro that takes a literal number and makes bound variables from `a` ... that can be used in the function.

If you are not using the arguments why not make a macro that does this:

```
(defmacro jlambda2 (&rest body)
  `(lambda (&rest #:rest) ,@body))
```

The result takes any number of arguments and just ignores it:

```
(defparameter *test* (jlambda2 (print "hello")))
(disassemble *test*)
;Disassembly of function :lambda
;(CONST 0) = "hello"
;0 required arguments
;0 optional arguments
;Rest parameter <!-- takes any numer of arguments
;No keyword parameters
;4 byte-code instructions:
;0     (const&push 0)                      ; "hello"
;1     (push-unbound 1)
;3     (calls1 142)                        ; print
;5     (skip&ret 2)
;nil

(funcall *test* 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
; ==> "hello" (prints "hello" as side effect)
```

**EDIT**

Now that I know what you are up to I have an answer for you. Your initial function does not need to be runtime dependent so all functions indeed have a fixed arity, so what we need to make is currying or partial application.

```
;; currying
(defmacro fixlam ((&rest args) &body body)
  (let ((args (reverse args)))
    (loop :for arg :in args
          :for r := `(lambda (,arg) ,@body)
                 :then `(lambda (,arg) ,r)
          :finally (return r))))

(fixlam (a b c) (+ a b c)) 
; ==> #<function :lambda (a) (lambda (b) (lambda (c) (+ a b c)))>


;; can apply multiple and returns partially applied when not enough
(defmacro fixlam ((&rest args) &body body)
  `(let ((lam (lambda ,args ,@body)))
     (labels ((chk (args)
                (cond ((> (length args) ,(length args)) (error "too many args"))
                      ((= (length args) ,(length args)) (apply lam args))
                      (t (lambda (&rest extra-args)
                           (chk (append args extra-args)))))))
       (lambda (&rest args)
         (chk args)))))

(fixlam () "hello") ; ==> #<function :lambda (&rest args) (chk args)>

;;Same but the zero argument functions are applied right away:
(defmacro fixlam ((&rest args) &body body)
  `(let ((lam (lambda ,args ,@body)))
     (labels ((chk (args)
                (cond ((> (length args) ,(length args)) (error "too many args"))
                      ((= (length args) ,(length args)) (apply lam args))
                      (t (lambda (&rest extra-args)
                           (chk (append args extra-args)))))))
       (chk '()))))

(fixlam () "hello") ; ==> "hello"
```

Comment: Using `COMPILE` also has the problem that the function can't refer to surrounding lexical variables. So `(let ((foo "hello")) (jlambda 1 (print foo)))` won't work.

Comment: First of all, thanks to @Sylwester for your helpful answer! Confusing run-time and macroexpansion-time is definitely an issue here. (Not sure what you mean by “strange quotes”: when I ran it the word “hello” was printed. Maybe I made a typo somewhere?). Secondly, I'm posting an answer your question "Why?" as an edit to the original question, because it might help the discussion, and it's far too long to post here.

Comment: @jkiiski That is correct because it and `coerce` are just `eval` in disguise, however the number of arguments can be an expression referring to lexical variables in this case making it slightly better than OP version, but not much.

Comment: @AndyPage I have added some more that might help.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is lambda functions that can be applied either partially or fully, I don't think you need to pass the amount of parameters explicitly. You could just do something like this (uses Alexandria):

```
(defmacro jlambda (arglist &body body)
  (with-gensyms (rest %jlambda)
    `(named-lambda ,%jlambda (&rest ,rest)
       (cond ((= (length ,rest) ,(length arglist))
              (apply (lambda ,arglist ,@body) ,rest))
             ((> (length ,rest) ,(length arglist))
              (error "Too many arguments"))
             (t (apply #'curry #',%jlambda ,rest))))))


CL-USER> (jlambda (x y) (format t "X: ~s, Y: ~s~%" x y))
#<FUNCTION (LABELS #:%JLAMBDA1046) {1003839D6B}>
CL-USER> (funcall * 10)  ; Apply partially
#<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST ALEXANDRIA.0.DEV::MORE) :IN CURRY) {10038732DB}>
CL-USER> (funcall * 20)  ; Apply fully
X: 10, Y: 20
NIL
CL-USER> (funcall ** 100) ; Apply fully again
X: 10, Y: 100
NIL
CL-USER> (funcall *** 100 200) ; Try giving a total of 3 args
; Debugger entered on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Too many arguments" {100392D7E3}>
```

**Edit:** Here's also a version that lets you specify the arity. Frankly, I don't see how this could possibly be useful though. If the user cannot refer to the arguments, and nothing is done with them automatically, then, well, nothing is done with them. They might as well not exist.

```
(defmacro jlambda (arity &body body)
  (with-gensyms (rest %jlambda n)
    `(let ((,n ,arity))
       (named-lambda ,%jlambda (&rest ,rest)
         (cond ((= (length ,rest) ,n)
                ,@body)
               ((> (length ,rest) ,n)
                (error "Too many arguments"))
               (t (apply #'curry #',%jlambda ,rest)))))))


CL-USER> (jlambda (+ 1 1) (print "hello"))
#<CLOSURE (LABELS #:%JLAMBDA1085) {1003B7913B}>
CL-USER> (funcall * 2)
#<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (&REST ALEXANDRIA.0.DEV::MORE) :IN CURRY) {1003B7F7FB}>
CL-USER> (funcall * 5)
"hello" 
"hello"
```

**Edit2:** If I understood correctly, you might be looking for something like this (?):

```
(defvar *stack* (list))

(defun jlambda (arity function)
  (lambda ()
    (push (apply function (loop repeat arity collect (pop *stack*)))
          *stack*)))


CL-USER> (push 1 *stack*)
(1)
CL-USER> (push 2 *stack*)
(2 1)
CL-USER> (push 3 *stack*)
(3 2 1)
CL-USER> (push 4 *stack*)
(4 3 2 1)
CL-USER> (funcall (jlambda 4 #'+)) ; take 4 arguments from the stack 
(10)                               ; and apply #'+ to them
CL-USER> (push 10 *stack*)
(10 10)
CL-USER> (push 20 *stack*)
(20 10 10)
CL-USER> (push 30 *stack*)
(30 20 10 10)
CL-USER> (funcall (jlambda 3 [{reduce #'*} #'list])) ; pop 3 args from 
(6000 10)                                            ; stack, make a list
                                                     ; of them and reduce 
                                                     ; it with #'*
```

Comment: This is a promising idea, but since the point of my language is to force the use of point-free style, my thinking was to avoid (and in fact prevent) the programmer from naming a function's arguments and referring to those names within the body of the function. I don't know yet if this will work. Rough example using [curry-compose-reader-macros](http://eschulte.github.io/curry-compose-reader-macros/):

Comment: Correction: this (untested) example using curry-compose-reader-macros should return 10: `(funcall (jlambda 1 {reduce #'+}) (list 1 2 3 4))`

Comment: @AndyPage But why even use `JLAMBDA` there? Simple `(funcall {reduce #'+} (list 1 2 3 4))` works. I'm not sure how that is actually supposed to work anyway. The lambda just returns the curried function; it doesn't ever call it (it's basically same as `(funcall (jlambda (x) {reduce #'+}) (list 1 2 3 4))` with my code). Is the idea that the return value of the body will automatically be `FUNCALL`ed with the arguments?

Comment: Something like that, yes. My vague plan is to write a custom REPL that automatically funcalls functions expressed in this language (which will start to look less and less like Lisp, probably more like Haskell or a stack-based language like Forth, where a function's arguments do not need to be mentioned explicitly because they each consume some values from the top of the stack and leave some on top). Perhaps there's a flaw in my idea though. I really appreciate your input!